# How to make cell content in ag-grid centered vertically?

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to decrease the row height of ag-grid by setting `gridOptions.rowHeight`. While this indeed decreases the row height, but the content is not centered vertically in the row. What's the best way to do this?

I also tried changing the `grid-size` parameter of the theme, but it runs into the same issue.

Here's the grid without any `gridOptions`. I measured the row height to be `42px` (although the docs say that it should be `25px`).

[image]

Here's what I get when I reduce the row height to `36px` (`gridOptions={{ rowHeight: 36 }}`):

[image]

Notice that the content is no longer vertically centered.

This becomes even more apparent when I increase the row size to `100px`. The content is clearly not centered.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cell content can be vertically aligned using css only.

```css
.ag-cell {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You can also add inline styles in the column definitions.

```js
<AgGridReact
  rowHeight={50}
  defaultColDef={{
    cellStyle: (params) => ({
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center"
    })
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64058096/decreasing-row-height-in-ag-grid]

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm! Surprised that the docs don't address this.

Comment: This works. But the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` doesn't work since the cell is `displayed: flex`. Result: The text overlaps its cell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a ag-grid custom cell renderer that contained images that should be vertically centered.

I solved it by adding a CSS class to the cell renderer during the `init()` call...

```
init(params: MyCellRendererParams) {

    const parentElement = params.eParentOfValue;
    parentElement.classList.add("my-cell-renderer-parent");

    // ...
}
```

that styled its child in verically centered and...

```
.my-cell-renderer-parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

... added a `text-overflow: ellipsis` to all `ag-cell-wrappers`-children (since the `overflow` attribute isn't working anymore with `display: flex` on the parent):

```
.my-cell-renderer-parent .ag-cell-wrapper {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```